# Accessing json data in flask html page

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a Python/Flask application. In views.py I'm querying a database and returning a pagination object to the html page for rendering. The model object returned here includes a name attribute which is accessed like so on the HTML page:

```
{% for item in passed_items.items %}
    {{item.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

This outputs correctly. The object ALSO has an attribute which is JSON encoded. I'm unable to access this data correctly.

```
{% for item in passed_items.items %}
    {{item.json}}
{% endfor %}
```

Will output all of the JSON correctly, but I can't access any specific information within the JSON. For example, item.json will output:

```
{"location":"here", "city":"there"}
```

But I am unable to access specific information such as location or city. I know the JSON is encoded correctly because I copy and pasted it into a python terminal and was able to access it. For some reason it seems like the python isn't recognizing the data outputted as a dict or as JSON. Here's what I've tried:

```
{% for item in passed_items.items %}
    {{item.json["location"]}}
    {{item.json['location']}}
    {{item.json.location}}
{% endfor %}
```

None of these gave any output. Any tips on how to access this data? Or how to get it recognized as a dicitonary or JSON? I feel like I've spent way too much time trying to access a simple JSON object here, haha.

Thanks for the help!

Edit: I've confirmed through typing:

```
{% for json in item.json %}
    {{json}}
{% endfor %}
```

That it is just treating each character as an element and not recognizing it as a dictionary or JSON format. That for loop outputs each character individually instead of the key/value pairs I want.

Edit2: Thanks guys, yeah I used json.loads() in my views.py to process the JSON first. Then I'm able to access it fine in the html page later on. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Is `json` a string or is it a Python dictionary? It has to be the latter for your syntax to work.

Comment: JSON is a *serialisation format*; you can represent objects and lists and values in text and deserialise it again to get the same data. But when serialised to JSON it is *just a string*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json attribute is probably a string, you can convert it to a a dictionary like this:

```
import json

data = {
    "name": "Johnson",
    "json": '{"array":[1,2,3],"boolean":true,"null":null,"number":123,"object":{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"},"string":"Hello World"}'
}

data['json'] = json.loads(data['json'])
print data['json']['number']
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that would work. Any idea how to do this in a HTML file with the flask renderer? There's a lot of items in the list so I'm trying to avoid having to edit them all in the views.py.

Comment: @user3666149: it's trivial enough to process the list of items in Python code. It's harder to provide your template with access to the `json` module.